# Where to find the Mona Lisa icon from Windows 3.1?

Tags: windows, icons, windows-3.1

In the old Windows 3.1 days I had an icon of an expressive and very good pixel-art reproduction of DaVinci's Mona Lisa portrait.  I'd like to have this icon again, but I couldn't find it anywhere.  **Which .DLL file was it located in?**  The icon looked like this:

[image: http://www.studiolo.org/Mona/MonaIcon.gif]

I checked into `moricons.dll` and some other files from the Windows 3.11 distribution, but still couldn't find it.

Comment: WOW, I remember this...

Comment: Why not convert that .gif version to an .ico?

Comment: Please tell us why if you want more mod points :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like the icon is in `progman.exe`, the Program Manager executable file. In Windows XP, you can still find the icon in `%SystemRoot%\system32\progman.exe`...

[image: Program Manager icons]

After rediscovering this, I think I remember that when you manually created a shortcut in Program Manager, the icons embedded in progman.exe were provided as default choices, or you could click a Browse button to open another .ico or .dll file like moricons.dll. But it's been so long ago, I don't have a copy to play with to confirm, and haven't been able to find information about it online.

Comment: +1 and I remember this being the default set of icons too.

Comment: I notice the Windows XP version is slightly different (dark yellow for the frame, instead of the original bright yellow; dark green grass instead of bright green). I think I remember these changes were introduced in Windows 95. If you ever used the Mona Lisa icon in Windows 3.1, you may remember the icon looked too bright compared to other icons.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was examining files with "additional" icons, and completely forgot what in Windows 3.x Program Manager had extensive set of addtitional icons too! And you are completely right on default icon choices - `moricons.dll` has "more icons" in addtion to icons in `progman.exe`

Comment: Yes, exactly, 3.11 have brighter icon than XP,

Answer (score 11):

Although I don't remember which .DLL this image is from, in the hopes of solving your problem I've taken your image and converted it with Adobe Photoshop (and one other proprietary command-line tool called "PNG2ICO") to a .ico file for you.  You can download it from here:

[image]
  Mona Lisa icon file (2,238 bytes)
  http://www.lumbercartel.ca/images/interesting/monalisa.ico

*Thanks for that nice trip down memory lane!*

Comment: paint.net would do direct saving to .ico with a plugin

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! Good scaling 144x144 -> 32x32

Comment: BTW, there is a plugin for Photoshop to read and write windows icon format, also GIMP2 supports it natively